# url pattern is not updating in web.xml in servlet application

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

hi i have a small servlet application which running in tomcat. in my web.xml i have given url pattern as test4 and form action in html also i given same and i was working fine. after some time i changed my url as test in both places and i run the application then it is throwing HTTP Status 404 - /ServletEx/test4

here my doubt is why the url is not updating . i clean the project from eclipse and i deleted tomcat and reconfigured even though it not updating. can any body plz tell me why it is not updating and how to update it. and one more doubt is my application is not there in tomcat webapps folder i think i should  be there after deploying.

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ex.ExampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
                                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="test">

            Please enter your username      
            <input type="text" name="un"/><br>      

            Please enter your password
            <input type="text" name="pw"/>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">            

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the old mapping still works even after you've changed it?

Comment: 1)remove tomcat `work` directory 2) remove `webapps/yourapp` directory 3) restart 4) ensure that `webapps/yourapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` contains your updated web.xml

Comment: @pedrofb thanks for your reply OK I will remove my work directory from tomcat but as I told you before in tomcat webapps my application is not there ..I am using tomcat 7.x zip

Comment: @kayaman yes it is taking old url

Comment: @suri, if you are running Tomcat from eclipse, the tomcat directory will be in `%ECLIPSEWORKSPACE%\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`

Comment: thanks for your reply i found webapp folder and deleted work as well as my application even though it is taking same old url..